# web.config - how to prevent all inheritance

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, web-config

We have an app as a root application on the server in /.

We have another application in /lite/ virtual root set up as its own application.

Both use EnterpriseLibrary, but obviously the /lite/ version has different settings.

The problem is that it wants to inherit all kinds of things from the web.config of the "parent" application.

Note that on some servers, it is quite likely that only the /lite/ will exist, so we can't rely on being able to inherit anyway, because a parent web.config may not always exist.

I found references to using the `<location>` and `<remove>`, but we didn't have a lot of success, because there were so many different things which had to be done.

Is there a simple way to make a virtual root simply be autonomous from a "parent" web.config?

Comment: tried configuring lite as a different app in IIS?

Comment: @naveen, it is a separate app.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the inheritInChildApplications attribute your root application's web.config:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
     ...
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the applicationHost.config file (%WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv\Config) and add the attribute enableConfigurationOverride="false" to your child app pool settings:

```
<add name="ChildAppPool" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" enableConfigurationOverride="false">
    <processModel identityType="NetworkService" />
</add>
```