# Does inheritInChildApplications Web.config attribute work in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance, web-config

We have an MVC3 application deployed on IIS 7.5, and now need to deploy another app in a subdirectory of the main one. After running into Web.config inheritance conflict we tried to wrap the system.web section of the parent app's config file in `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">`, as recommended in the accepted answer to [web.config - how to prevent all inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296168/web-config-how-to-prevent-all-inheritance), but we're getting an error:

> InheritInChildApplications cannot be set to "false" if the location
>   path is referring to machine.config or the root web.config.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: did you find solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

There was a known bug in 51Degrees.mobi component which accessed its config in a way that caused the application to crash when inheritInChildApplications property was used in the config file.
Apparently it has been fixed in newer library version as described [here](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/workitem/8728).